# jquery perform another function in last "for" run

Tags: javascript

I have js objects and a function as follow:

```
function my_function(data){
    var cont = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < (data.length); i++) {                   
       var info     = data[i];  
       var r_id     = info['ID'];
       cont.unshift(r_id);  //example: [12,158,125,126,126]
    };  
    //I need to save the last id (in this case, 126) as `saved_id` to be used in another function                   
};  

var saved_id;
```

Now, I need to save the last number (in this case, 126) as a separate variable (as `saved_id`) to be used in another function.

How would I do this so that when the `for` function runs and if it is the last run, then it performs another function (in this case, updates the `saved_id` variable with the last id number)?

Comment: You can run a loop in inverse order and have a `r_id` variable global...

Comment: Is `[12,158,125,126,126]` the final order in `cont` or the order you call `unshift` on `cont`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var saved_id;
function my_function(data){
    var cont = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < (data.length); i++) {                   
       var info     = data[i];  
       var r_id     = info['ID'];
       cont.unshift(r_id);  
       saved_id = r_id;//update saved_id every time last value will be in it when loop ends
    };  

};
```

Comment: I wouldn't write it that way, because it will always look like a mistake. The value is set in every step of the loop, but only the last time it is set is relevant. If you always want to use the first element of the `cont` then use `saved_id = cont[0]` after the loop. if you always want to use the last `ID` in `data` no matter how you add them to `cont` then use `saved_id = data[data.length-1].ID` @steveKim

Comment: I see what you mean. I understand what you mean and will be reflected on my function. Thank you for the insight! =)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a if statement that checks for last id and saves it.

```
if(i== (data.length-1))
 {
  saved_id= r_id;
  // you can also call some other function here
 }
```